# Conditional deletion from mySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a list of clients containing some numbers. Different clients may share these numbers between each other (one client may "borrow" some of his numbers to the other) but if the "borrower" gets deleted he has to return those numbers.

My table structure looks like that:

```
id | client | range_num_up | range_num_down | ... | former
```

What I am trying to achieve here is that:
- if the numbers assigned to the client had no former: delete them from database
- else the numbers must be assigned to the former once again

I am aware of *SELECT IF* statements in the mySQL but I am not quite sure how to tie it up together with one query.

I already tried something like:

```
SELECT IF(former is NULL, '', former) former FROM numbers_pool WHERE id = 3
```

Which returns to me a name of the former owner of the numbers. Now I would like to use that information to handle the query along. What I image is following scenario:

```
if reply == '' {
    DELETE THAT ENTRY
}
else {
    UPDATE THE NAME OF THE CLIENT WITH RECEIVED FORMER
}
```

Any tips and help is appreciated.

@edit

To be precise: I know I can you DELETE but that still does not cover the second scenario in which I would like to update that record. So I am looking for one-query-solution.

Comment: "if the numbers assigned to the client had no former: delete them from database" unless I've missed something, what's wrong with just `DELETE FROM numbers_pool WHERE Former IS NULL AND id = 3`? Maybe there's more to it which isn't entirely clear from your description. Perhaps giving us some sample data and then showing us the expected result based on that data would help.

Comment: It is not wrong I just would like to handle both cases in one query as the last code snippet says.

Comment: you can't do both DELETE and UPDATE in a single statement - they are different types of query. You could write a short routine (e.g. procedure or function, or just a routine in a script file you load and execute) which would carry out both operations simultaneously - and perhaps it would be sensible to place them both within a transaction as well, so if anything goes wrong you can roll back the whole lot and not leave your data in an ambiguous state.

Comment: Could you be more specific or show some example maybe? I will be using a function as the query will be loaded from a flask app.

Comment: you can find examples of how to write a mysql function in plenty of places if you're unsure how to create one. Once you do that...within the function it's just multiple SQL statements separated by semicolons. Can you be more specific about what part of that you don't understand?

Comment: how can I have control over executing the statements: i.e. I want to execute UPDATE if 0 rows were affected by the DELETE statement (or just have any quasi-conditional based on previous query result). Do I make myself clean or this doesn't make sense?

Comment: There is a way to find out how many rows were affected by the previous query, yes. you can find this out in a few moments [on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+get+rows+affected&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=mysql+get+rows+affected&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2944j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Although, I think that doing that doesn't really match your scenario. You said you wanted to do an update when the "former" field is not null...you can do that without referring to the DELETE operation at all. Forget the notion that you have to process each row one by one - SQL is much more efficient at doing operation on _sets_ of data. So you can do one DELETE to delete all the rows where former is NULL, and one UPDATE to update all the clients based on those rows where Former is not null. I think you perhaps need to study SQL in a bit more detail if you don't realise this

Comment: I do know that but in this case it is all about deleting just a single entry which user will pick on the frontend side of an app.

Comment: ok well the first check the value of `former` using a SELECT and read the value into a variable. If you get a value, then do the necessary update. If you get NULL, do the DELETE instead.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for all your help. If you be kind enough to post all of that as an answer I would happily mark "solved" and up vote you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do both `DELETE` and `UPDATE` in a single statement - they are different types of query. You could write a short routine (e.g. procedure or function, or just a routine in a script file you load and execute) which would execute all the necessary statements in a single operation.

The logic should be fairly simple:

First check the value of `former` using a `SELECT` and read the value into a variable. If you get a value, then do the necessary `UPDATE`. If you get `NULL`, do the `DELETE` instead. You don't need to rely on the result of the DELETE to decide what to do with the UPDATE (or vice versa).